Flutter Android Studio open other file when debug
Please help me.
When i debugging my flutter application, android studio started opening not the file where I set the breakpoint, but the same one but without the breakpoint and the ability to edit the file. How to disable this?
image with brackpoint
image without brackpoint
Searching for settings didn't yield any results

This is my question to.
I hope that a solution will be found to fix this problem and that I will be able to see it when I answer you

I was facing the same issue with all 3.2x Flutter SDK versions.
The only workaround, for now, is to downgrade.
I'm currently getting back to Flutter 3.19.6 • channel stable, with Dart 3.3.4
You can find all previous versions here : https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive
Hope this will help
